# Get string from between tags whilst retaining rest of string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like:

```
<price>£10</price>Rimmel Super-Quick Mascara
```

I want to extract the string out of the `<price>` tags and also retain the string after the tags too. So:

```
$price = £10
$desc = Rimmel Super-Quick Mascara
```

How can I do this with PHP? I have attempted to use the following function I found but I get an unknown error in the regex, though I can't identify where.

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname ?.*>(.*)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: The function works just fine if I use these: `$str = "<price>£10</price>Rimmel Super-Quick Mascara"; $tag = 'price';` as parameters to the function.

Comment: I'm starting to feel slightly dirty pasting this link into comments so often... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Andrius My IDE highlights an error in the regex though it can't define it, and the script returns server error 500.

Comment: An HTTP 500 error implies there's something else going on rather than this being just an error in your PHP code; it's an Internal Server Error normally caused (on Apache) by something wrong in an .htaccess file (or, to a lesser extent, one of the httpd-*.conf files).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for both price and text:

```
$str = '<price>£10</price>Rimmel Super-Quick Mascara';

$text = preg_replace('/<[a-z]+>(.*?)<\/?[a-z]+>(.*?)/','$1|$2',$str);

$data = explode('|',$text);

var_dump($data);
```

response:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '£10' (length=3)
  1 => string 'Rimmel Super-Quick Mascara' (length=26)
```

In your function :

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname) {
    $text = preg_replace("/<".$tagname.">(.*?)<\/?".$tagname.">(.*?)/","$1|$2",$string);
    $data = explode('|',$text);
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$pattern = "/.*?<$tagname.*?>(.*?)<\/$tagname.*?>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches );
return $matches[ 0 ][ 0 ];
```